# itext7 + pdfHtml: how set portrait orientation and fit content on ConvertToPdf

Tags: itext, itext7, pdfhtml

I did a simple html to pdf conversion getting a landscape orientation.
In the [pdfHtml release notes](https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfhtml/releases) I see that the default orientation should be portrait but I got a landscape.

I'm not able to find the option/parameter/setting to do it.

Probably it is in the ConverterProperties object hidden to my eyes :-(

Any suggestion?

Here is my very simple code

```
public byte[] HtmlToPdf(string html)
{
    using (Stream htmlSource = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
    using (MemoryStream pdfDest = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlSource, pdfDest, converterProperties);

        return pdfDest.ToArray();
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT after answers (I got the right orientation!):**

Now I have to find a way to scale down the content in order to fit the content and have the right margins without cutting the image.

```
public static byte[] HtmlToPdf(string html)
{
    using (Stream htmlSource = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
    using (MemoryStream pdfDest = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfDest));
        pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlSource, pdfDocument, converterProperties);

        return pdfDest.ToArray();
    }
}
```

HTML result:

[image]

PDF result:

[image]

Comment: quick comment, the default orientation has only changed if you're using a ledger page size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set orientation to Landscape in iText 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347293/how-to-set-orientation-to-landscape-in-itext-7)

Comment: @AndréLemos, both answers have been useful, I'm new on this topic. So I edited the text with the current result. Is there a way to scale in order to fit the content and have the margin on the right side without cutting the content? Do I have to work on the HTML or on the itext7 conversion configuration?

Comment: well, there are multiple ways to go around it. look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341485/how-to-make-a-html-page-in-a4-paper-size-pages and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869248/page-size-and-formatting-of-pdf-using-itext-pdfhtml

Comment: @AndréLemos thanks for the really good related articles. I did some test but it's too hard in my context to find the right way. The html is produced by an external application, so I should transform it. These articles are very good to understand that it's hard and in addition itext7 produces a couple of unexpected white lines in the rendering. I found a good solution changing the library from itext7 to dinkToPdf based on wkhtmltopdf, with the result I attached that could be useful to other developers... maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved changing the library from itext7 to DinkToPdf. I found it very simple to use and enough to my needs.

---

**The MVC controller after changing the library to DinkToPdf**

```
public byte[] PdfCreatorController(IConverter converter)
    string html = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

    var globalSettings = new GlobalSettings
    {
        ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
        Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
        Margins = new MarginSettings { Top = 10 },
        DocumentTitle = "Report",    
        Out = string.Empty,
    };

    var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
    {
        PagesCount = true,
        HtmlContent = html,
        WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8", UserStyleSheet = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "assets", "styles.css") },
    };

    var pdf = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
    {
        GlobalSettings = globalSettings,
        Objects = { objectSettings }
    };

    return = _converter.Convert(pdf);
}
```

PDF Result

[image]